# I/O operation on closed file. when trying to read a file content on django model save()

Tags: django

This is my Django Model where I'm trying to store the content of an uploaded file in field attachments:

```
class CsvFile(models.Model):
    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    uid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=str(uuid4()))
    date = models.DateField(null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now().date())
    time = models.TimeField(null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now().time())
    original_filename = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True)
    attachment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=f"csv/", blank=True)

    def save_file_content_to_attachment(self, file):
        try:
            with file.open('r') as f:
                self.attachment = f.read()
        except (FileNotFoundError, ValueError):
            self.attachment = ''

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Save the uploaded file to the csv_path field
        self.original_filename = self.file.name  

        # Print a message to help troubleshoot the issue
        print(f"Saving file content to attachment for file {self.file.name}")

        # Save the file content to the attachment field
        self.save_file_content_to_attachment(self.file)

        super(CsvFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Delete the file from storage
        try:
            default_storage.delete(self.file.name)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass  # File does not exist, so we can ignore the exception

        super(CsvFile, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Unfotunately an upload of a file fails with I/O error

[image]

Here is the full backtrace
https://hastebin.skyra.pw/mizawicane.css

Can somebody shed light into why this is not working?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning @aaron I've added the trace as a pastebin as otherwise stackoverflow did not except the change

Comment: The link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In case others run into the same problem.
This is how I solved it:

```
def save_file_content_to_attachment(self, file):
    # Make sure the file is open in read mode
    if not file.closed:
        file.open('r')

    # Make sure the file is a file-like object that supports reading
    if hasattr(file, 'read'):
        try:
            # Read the contents of the file and save them to the attachment field
            self.attachment = file.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # If the file is not found, set the attachment field to an empty string
            self.attachment = ''
    else:
        # If the file is not a file-like object that supports reading, set the attachment field to an empty string
        self.attachment = ''
```